# Way to calculate difference between Tab Filter and Overall in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a calculated value in Google Data Studio that a client wants to see as follows:

Result = Value (No filters on page applied) - Value (Filters on page applied dynamically)

I don't know how to calculate or accomplish this in Google Data Studio or if this is possible. Can someone show me if this solution is possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are two workarounds:

**Parameters**

Instead of using filters, create a parameter1 and a field with the function

```
Value - 
case when parameter1=some_field then Value
else 0 end
```

**Blend**

Duplicate the data source and hide all field which shall not be filtered. Blend this data source with the original one and use as joining keys the dimension which are not filtered. Use the field `Value` in both sets as metrics and rename it as filtered / not filtered.

Add a chart and add in this chart a metric field with a formula substracting these two `Value` fields.